# Should my energy collectors be running even when I'm logged off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

I have a private server running Tekkit and I'm finding that some (perhaps all) of my [energy collectors](http://equivalentexchange.wikispaces.com/Energy+Collector) are running 24x7, even when nobody else is logged on (supposing I log off in the evening, when I check on it in the morning I can find half a stack or so of dark matter waiting for me in a chest).

**Are energy collectors supposted to work even when nobody is logged onto the server?** Its nice having all of these resources, but I can't help but wonder if this is a bug.

My friend and I are the only people whitelisted on the server and I've checked the logs so I know that nobody else is logged on.  Also neither of us have placed any world anchors or anything like that.  The collectors are close to the spawn, I'm not sure if that makes any difference or not.

Answer (score 4):

The server will by default keep a certain number of chunks near the server spawn loaded at all times, regardless of people logged in or actual chunk loaders. To my knowledge there's no way to disable this at all in Minecraft 1.2.5.

Comment: Do you have any more detail on how to tell which chunks will be kept loaded?

Comment: You can't in Minecraft, or with any of the mods in Tekkit. There are some mods that may show you, specifically ChickenChunks might let you see all chunks loaded though I'm not sure if CB's interface that has that info shows all loaded chunks or only chunks loaded by his chunk loaders.

Comment: Specifically, most mods with a chunkloader have some way of viewing the chunks that mod is keeping loaded, but not special cases like the spawn zone. It's just not something that Mojang needed to worry about since there's no need to keep places loaded in vanilla Minecraft from a gameplay point of view. The spawn point is kept loaded as an optimisation for the first person reconnecting to the server.

Answer (score 1):

128 blocks out in any directions from spawn is loaded. when you arent on the server. you can change this in the server properties. ;D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed in the technology that runs chunks but if it's near spawn there's a good chance the chunk is staying "loaded" and will run your collectors persistently.

I'm sure you're aware but SMP (that's hosted somewhere) doesn't function like SSP in that even if no one is on things will keep on trucking like there are.

Answer (score 0):

Near the spawn some chunks are always loaded. I never investigated how much, but you can test it by simply dropping items everywhere around a certain area and log off. Check back after a little more than 5 minutes. Items despawn after 5 minutes so in every loaded chunk there should be no items anymore. Unloaded chunks will still have the items on the ground.